# Installing fortify /bootstrap in new laravel 8 app I got error

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

I need to install fortify /bootstrap in the new laravel eight app
and running the home page, I got an page with message (https://prnt.sc/22sllw5)  /error message :

```
Two Factor Authentication
Recovery Codes:
WW9rE3LNFi-h5knxwle2v
43nN0mxYVy-4p5lLHFcCD

....
“Disable” button
```

If in config/fortify.php I have :

```
'limiters' => [
    'login' => 'login',
    'two-factor' => 'two-factor',
],


'views' => true,


'features' => [
    Features::registration(),
],
```

Also I modified app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;
use App\Actions\Fortify\ResetUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
        Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
        Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
        Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

        Fortify::registerView(function () {
            return view('auth.register');
        });

        Fortify::loginView(function () {
            return view('auth.login');
        });


        RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
            $email = (string) $request->email;

            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($email.$request->ip());
        });

        RateLimiter::for('two-factor', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
        });
    }
}
```

In routes/web.php :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::view('/home', 'home')->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

How can I fix it?
I want some simple decisions, as I do not some complicated register/login functionality...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I added printscreen of error message

Comment: Installing the fortify with fersh  laravel app doesn't raise any errors for me

Comment: What you're seeing is not an error. Those are recovery codes for use if/when you screw up your 2FA device link.

Comment: Which can be simple decision for it ?